# Why droped RabbitMQ component in ApacheCamel 4.0.0?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, rabbitmq-exchange

It would be cool if Claus Ibsen answered this question...

Why was the [rabbitmq](/questions/tagged/rabbitmq) component removed?
Perhaps there is some idea for this or a higher meaning?

Now my team wants to move to [apache-camel](/questions/tagged/apache-camel) 4.0.0, but now they need to use [spring-rabbit](/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) in which there are no "passive" and "skipExchangeDeclare" flags.

Perhaps these flags are planned as an extension of the [spring-rabbit](/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) component at the Camel level?

After all, now, I will have to transfer an elegant solution with a full configuration of the components in application.yaml to writing Config.class with writing a check for queues and exchanges

I checked probably the entire StackOverFlow for a similar question, GitHub and other forums, but I did not find answer.

Comment: This question should rather be asked in the ML or the chat of Camel see https://camel.apache.org/community/support/

Comment: I can't recall exactly why but I guess is to avoid having to maintain 2 components for RabbitMQ